# How to copy different versions of the same folder in excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

What I want to do is to use Excel to make copies of folders after checking them if it exists. But if it exists, instead of deleting the folder and create a new one (I've already figured out how to do this using the kill/Rmdir/Mkdir functions), I would like to create a new one using the same folder name, but with something like (1), (2) at the end of the folder name to differentiate between them. Also, I would like it to be a loop, so as to obtain a later version if previous versions already exists.

Example:
original folder name abc
first copy (in the same directory abc(1))
second copy (in the same directory abc(2))
=>I want to do a loop to check each version, and then create a new folder if it doesn't already exists.

```
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill strDir & "*.*"
    RmDir strDir
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Dir(strDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    strDir = Destination & "\" "
    MkDir strDir
    End If
```

This is what I currently have, and I'm using

```
If Dir(strDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
```

to check if the folder already exists.

Any help on how to do a loop check and create a folder with incremental version names? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim strDirVersion as Integer
If Dir(strDir, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
    strDirVersion = 1
    Do While Dir(strDir & "(" & strDirVersion & ")", vbDirectory) <> ""
        strDirVersion = strDirVersion + 1
    Loop
    strDir = strDir & "(" & strDirVersion & ")"
End If
```

This will leave strDir with either the initial value, or with a suffix of `(n)` where `n` is the first integer (starting with `1`) that can be found for which a directory doesn't already exist.

Note:  If strDir had a value of `abc` and directories `abc`, `abc(1)` and `abc(3)` already existed, this would return `abc(2)`, not `abc(4)` - i.e. it sees that `2` is available before it notices that `3` has been used.

Comment: This is amazing and works perfectly! Thanks!!! I really need to practice my looping more :)